# Free memory after iphone animation

Tags: iphone, memory-management, animation

My app crashes due to memory building up after every animation.

Here is my sample code:

```
-(IBAction) shoot: (id)delegate{
[gun setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"animation_machin_guns_320x480_7.png"]];
UIImage *frame1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"animation_machin_guns_320x480_1.png"];
UIImage *frame2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"animation_machin_guns_320x480_2.png"];
UIImage *frame3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"animation_machin_guns_320x480_3.png"];
UIImage *frame4 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"animation_machin_guns_320x480_4.png"];
UIImage *frame5 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"animation_machin_guns_320x480_5.png"];
UIImage *frame6 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"animation_machin_guns_320x480_6.png"];
UIImage *frame7 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"animation_machin_guns_320x480_7.png"];    
gun.animationImages = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:frame1, frame2, frame3, frame4, frame5, frame6, frame7,nil];
gun.animationDuration = 1;
gun.animationRepeatCount = 1; 
[gun startAnimating];
[frame1 release];
[frame2 release];
[frame3 release];
[frame4 release];
[frame5 release];
[frame6 release];
[frame7 release];}
```

Releasing the frames doesn't seem to do the magic.
I tried using this http://kosmaczewski.net/projects/iphone-image-cache/ for image caching but i guess I don't know how to use it properly since the memory builds up faster than using imageNamed.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:xxx];` with `[NSArray arrayWithObjects:xxx];`.

Currently, the array object is being retained twice (once effectively by `alloc` and once by `gun.animationImages = xxx`), but only released once (when the gun object is released, or the animationImages property is set to something new), meaning it will never be released.

The `arrayWithObjects` method returns an autoreleased object, meaning it doesn't need to be manually released by you.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you I would think about only animating parts of the screen or perhaps compressing the images into low quality jpgs or something along those lines.

Comment: I need all the screen to be animated and I've already minimized the file size for the images to as low as possible.